# Rank tag similarity to string in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, similarity

I have rather challenging task I need to solve about finding how likely some tags (2-3 words strings) will be similar to some bigger texts (1-2 sentences).

I mean - I have a list of tags and a list of sentences. I need to end up with kind of sorted array of sentences by their relevance to all tags.

I have tried some tools like `fuzzy-string-match` gem but the result is far away from what I need. Is there any tool allowing to do that, OR I need to implement my own algorythm which will split all text to arrays of smaller strings and compare they one-by-one with each tag using similarity sore?

Comment: Define "far away". There are many ways of matching text. If you're using Postgres you might try the [pg_trgm](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgtrgm.html) extension; trigrams do a pretty decent job of things like this. There's also the PG fuzzystrmatch extension. You may need to experiment with various matching algorithms (or, potentially, implement your own) to get exactly what you need, but without knowing any more, I'd give trigrams a shot.

Comment: @DaveNewton sying "far away" I mean that it returns totally different from reality percentage. An this is not surprising as I am trying to find how similar is big chunk of text to one word (and `fuzzy-string-match`) is meant to check ~same-length strings I believe.

I will definitely give a try `pg_trgm` stuff, but I would like to find something more DB agnostic, Ruby inmlementation of something similar

Comment: I don't think anyone can clearly answer your question (including ruby) until you can give a clear explanation of what this notion of "relevance" or "similarity" is.  If you have trouble putting that in an algorithm, it might make sense to at least give some examples of some that are close and some that are not (and perhaps include your thoughts on why they are close or far).